# Can't upload images to wordpress in vagrant VCCW environment

Tags: wordpress, upload, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am using vagrant vccw ( http://vccw.cc/ ) to do local WordPress development.

When I try to upload an image in WordPress I get the message:

> Error. Please try again later

I've tried waiting and done it several times, still no results.

I tried switching the settings in `default.yml` to be 8024 max upload size and transfer size, but no luck.

Any idea how to fix this? I am having a hard time designing the site for live use when I can't see where images will be placed because I can't upload them.

Comment: I've never used VCCW so don't have advice specific to that. First thing I'd do is open the browser console with F12 and look for Javascript errors when you try to upload an image. Do you get any? Next thing I'd check is to make sure the server can write and execute in the `wp-content/uploads/` folder. It needs execute permission so it can navigate through the folder.

Answer (score 2):

I can understand the problem, It has nothing to do with WordPress configuration. Try to install PHP GD library, WordPress internally uses it for resizing images while uploading.

Give it a try, I am sure it will solve your problem.

Thanks